# how to debug a web application in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, flask, visual-studio-debugging

I want to know how we can debug a application ex: facebook in chrome, how we can stepover each backend actions when we login into facebook. How the flow goes in backend when we login into FB...

can we do this in chrome without setting it any breakpoints ?

Comment: You cannot debug backend activity from a web browser, in general. Well, probably very close to universally.

Comment: @Pointy, how to debug our own applications with code available in system,  i have the code and without setting breakpoints i want to see the  flow of my application

Comment: The server-side code and the browser are completely separate environments.

Comment: @Pointy, yes server side code and browser are separate env,,, i want to debug an application to know the exact flow of the code .. i have Visual studio and code ...if i add breakpoints then while debugging its stopping at that point but i am not sure where all i have to set the breakpoints .

Comment: Hi rrr, please check if my answer help you handle this issue. If it helps you and handle this issue,you could consider accept it so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues. If not, please feel free to let us know. It is kind it you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> can we do this in chrome without setting it any breakpoints ?

As far as I know, it cannot be done. If you want to debug your project, you have to set breakpoint. **Besides**, you should have the sample and should use the localhost to debug it.

**First of all**, you should open the prject on VS and then debug it with Chrome.

**1)**, when you debug an asp net project, it usually have naming rules. If you open a new form page in Chrome, you can find the related page on the solution explorer, and set a breakpoint on the top of it.

**2)** Chrome can only debug Javascript code. If you want to debug it, you should press **F12** on Chrome to open the developer mode. You can see that the JS code of the current page is under the **Source** menu, you can set a breakpoint directly at the beginning of the script.

[image]

**Then** you can click on the UI button or menu to start debugging(both js and backend activity ). Also, when you enter a new  form page, just follow the above two steps to debug it.

**In addition**, since VS2017, you can just debug js in VS, enable option **Enable Javascript debugging for Asp.Net** under Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General.

Then, you can search under the solution explorer, find the current debug form page-->find the related js file, and set a breakpoint on the top of it. After it, you can start to debug the menu of asp net project.

**Note:** every time you enter a new page, you should search both front end and back end pages to set a breakpoint manually.