# Firestore database not working for some unknown error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and was creating a simple chat app using *firebase + react*, following a youtube tutorial

Authentication and storage works alright.

However, I can't use firestore database for some unknown reason. No errors are shown. I am using both storage and Firestore Database in test mode

(PS: I am **NOT** speaking of the realtime database, just the normal Firestore Database)
(PS#2: While initializing firestore database, I was asked to switch to **native mode** from google cloud console as the project didnot support **Datastore mode**. I didnot know what either of them meant and why was my project not supported, and thus switched to native mode as told)

I am new to firebase and was creating a simple chat app using *firebase + react*, following a youtube tutorial

I did all the firebase setup they asked. After that, I wrote the Authentication code and a Storage code and everything works fine

But, when I am trying to use FireStore Database to store information of how many users I have (so that I can implement a search functionality later), it simply ain't working! No errors are shown either. The FireStore Database is just blank.

Register.jsx:-

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { auth, storage, db } from './firebase.js';



const Register = () => {

    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [uploadError, setUploadError] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        setError("");
        setUploadError("");

        e.preventDefault();
        const displayName = e.target[0].value;
        const email = e.target[1].value;
        const password = e.target[2].value;
        const file = e.target[3].files[0];

        // firebase create USER
        try {
            const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

            const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);
            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

            uploadTask.on('state_changed',

                (err) => {
                    // unsuccessful uploads
                    setUploadError(err.message);
                },
                () => {
                    // successful uploads, we get a downloadable URL
                    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async (downloadURL) => {
                        setUploadError("");

                        // for adding userName(aka displayName) and photo to account
                        await updateProfile(res.user, {
                            displayName,
                            photoURL: downloadURL
                        });

                        // database used for search functionality

                        try {
                            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {
                                uid: res.user.id,
                                displayName,
                                email,
                                photoURL: downloadURL
                            });
                            console.log("User data successfully added to database!");
                        } catch (err) {
                            console.error("Error adding user data to database:", err);
                        }

                    });
                }
            );

        } catch (err) {
            setError(err.message);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="formContainer">
            <div className="formWrapper">
                <span className="logo">WebChat</span>
                <span className="title">Register</span>

                <form onSubmit={(e) => { handleSubmit(e) }} >
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Display Name" />
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="file" />
                    <button>Sign Up</button>
                    <p style={{ color: "red", textAlign: "center" }}>{error || uploadError}</p>
                </form>

                <p>Do you already have an account? Login</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Register;
```

I also tried to change FireStore Database rules to:-

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

but that doesn't work. Also, I have heard that doing it is insecure

I heard that chrome extensions may do it too... but I currently don't use any extension (except for google docs offline, and I tried disabling it, but, that doesn't help)

Please help me fix this problem...

Comment: What happens if you add `type="button"` to `<button>Sign Up</button>`, i.e. `<button type="button">Sign Up</button>`. Since "no errors are shown", I suspect that your form is possibly submitted before one or more  Firebase methods are triggered.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec 
Adding type="button" doesn't change anything, it still ain't uploading to my database. And no errors are shown again this time

How do I know if my form is getting submitted before the methods are fired? I mean authentication and storage works alright...only the firestore database

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so it's best if you debug locally and tell us the results of that. In this case: set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, and run the code in a debugger. Then check the value of each variable on each line. which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ...and how do I do that? any specific way or app...(I use vs code)? I am still new to programming and debug with console.log()'s and my way don't seem to reveal any problem...

Comment: [How to debug a web app in the browser](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+a+web+app+in+the+browser) is a bit beyond the scope of what we can do here, but that search gives some promising results, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62489635/how-to-debug-a-web-application-in-chrome. Logging values can also work, you just need to make sure you log *every* relevant value on *every* line, which ends up as *a lot* of output. Learning to debug with breakpoints in a debugger is well worth it in the long run.